# Puts function in avr skipping chars

Tags: c, terminal, microcontroller, avr

i have this issue, i have to print a string with a puts function that i've made, but it's doing something weird.
I hava a

```
unsigned char string[10];
```

Which i use to store the string. I made a custom gets (we cannot use libraries) and when i send the string trough the keybord with a terminal program(Mttty) it prints the string flawlessly.
But, when i use the puts, with a direct string it doesnt work, for example:

```
USART_gets(string);
USART_puts(string);
```

This code works, it prints the string exactly as i typed through the terminal, now the issue comes in this code:

```
USART_puts("Hello");
```

This one, on the terminal gives me this:

```
Hlo
```

Any ideas? Here´s my code for both the putchar and puts.

```
void USART_putchar( unsigned char caracter )
{
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
    UDR0 = caracter;
}
void USART_puts(unsigned int *string){
    while(*string){
        USART_putchar(*string++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE ERROR! Its not void USART_puts(unsigned int) it is USART_puts(unsigned char) ha! Doopy me!